# What is the Equavalent of Bitmap & Graphics (found in Windows Forms) in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, winforms, silverlight, graphics, bitmap

I have an application in windows forms that have the code with Bitmap and Graphics and now i would like to convert it to Silverlight and i would like to know the equavalent of Bitmap & Graphics (found in Windows Forms) in Silverlight. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608877%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) for bitmap in Silverlight or you can also use [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

As far as Graphics is concerned, I don't think so you will find anything equivalent of Graphics in Silverlight because it is based on totally different rendering engine as compared to Win Forms. May be you can use [Shape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape%28VS.95%29.aspx) and/or [Geometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry%28VS.95%29.aspx) classes